# Reading separate ints from a text file then skipping to the next line and repeating

Tags: java

How do I read 2 ints from one line of a text file then skip to the next line and read 2 more separate ints from that line etc. The ints are separated by a space.

Comment: Using `nextInt()` 2 times and `nextLine()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First post the code you already have next time ;)

You could use something like this:

```
String[] lines= /*The lines from your file*/;
for(String line:lines){ // For each String `line` in `lines`
 String[] numbers=line.split(" "); // Split `line` before and after " "
 int no1=Integer.parseInt(numbers[0]); // Get the first number (as String) and convert it to an int
 int no2=Integer.parseInt(numbers[1]); // Get the second number (as String) and convert it to an int
}
```

Let me know whether is works or not
Happy coding :) -Charlie